# Opencart 2x Request multiple rows data

Tags: php, module, controller, opencart

I try to make a simple image module. No errors, the only problem is data not saved(maybe)/not loaded everytime I visit this module back. Here's my code in controller:

```
if (isset($this->request->post['photo_image'])) {
   $photo_images = $this->request->post['photo_image'];
} elseif (isset($this->request->get['photo_image'])) {
   $photo_images = $this->model_module_photo->getProductImages($this->request->get['photo_image']);
} else {
   $photo_images = array();
}

$data['photo_images'] = array();

foreach ($photo_images as $photo_image) {
   if (is_file(DIR_IMAGE . $photo_image['image'])) {
      $image = $photo_image['image'];
      $thumb = $photo_image['image'];
   } else {
      $image = '';
      $thumb = 'no_image.png';
   }

   $data['photo_images'][] = array(
      'image'      => $image,
      'thumb'      => $this->model_tool_image->resize($thumb, 100, 100)
   );
}
```

I'm not sure about `isset($this->request->get['photo_image'])` code above. Because I took from product images controller. I think I miss on data request. Someone can help me figured it out?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you familiar with php enough to know what the `$_GET` array is?  For that condition to be true, `photo_image` needs to be part of your query string, if not, you're looking at either an empty array or post data populating your tpl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine but the problem seems in getting the module (edit module). Make sure you have set correct url for edit link. And also check whether variable **photo_image** exist in url or not. The url would be like **yoursite address/admin/....&photo_image=idOfmodule**

Comment: Sorry for late respond. Anyway, yes I'm missing on edit module. Forgot to include model. Thanks for your help =)